# Split a list of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I guess this is a very simple question but I cannot figure it out...
I have a list of strings:

```
List<String> List0 = "1","2","3","4","5"
```

I whish to split this string up into two OR skip the first two string and keep a list of the rest. Like so:

```
List1 = "1","2"

List2 = "3","4","5"
```

I have tried with:

```
list2 = list0.Skip(2);
```

or:

```
list2 = from x in list0.Skip<string>(2) select x;
```

Comment: And why is the first approach not working?

Comment: Is it a list? is it an array? What does it have to do with MVC?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that. When I debug the list turns out NULL. It returnsn"System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableiterator<string,string>

Comment: What type is List0 ?

Comment: List0 is a list of strings. List<String>. I have edited my question.

Comment: @CasperNybroe debugging linq in the debugger can be tricky because it wraps the actual data in enumerators that don;t clearly show what the result of the enumeration will be.  It's easier to debug if you convert it to a concrete collection via `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Comment: You need to run a `ToList()`. `list0.Skip(2).ToList()` or `(from x in list0.Skip<string>(2) select x).ToList()`

Comment: I'm confused why you would see a `WhereSelectEnumerableiterator` when you don't use `Where()` in your sample code - have you posted the queries _exactly_ as they appear in code?

Comment: D Stanley and Amir - thank you. I just had to add .ToList() after Skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Skip` (and `Where`) return an `IEnumerable<T>`. If `list2` is a `List<string>` then you will need to either convert the query to a list:

```
list2 = list0.Skip(2).ToList();
```

or just declare it as an `IEnumerable<string>` if you don't need actual `List` functionality:

```
IEnumerable<string> list2;
```